# Why does send_keys("string") place spaces in between each character?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

So I am automating search terms from a list of lists. 
Right now I have:

```
search_terms = KeyWordExtract(keyWord_List)
browser.find_element_by_id('terms').send_keys(search_terms)



def KeyWordExtract(keyWord_List):

    myString = " ".join(keyWord_List)
    return myString
```

If I have a list of lists like this `keywords_list = [['nasa', 'rocket', 'hopkins'], ['tesla', 'elon', 'stanford'], ['asdasdsadasd']]` the search term (for the first list) will be 
`n a s a r o c k e t h o p k i n s`

But when I test out my KeyWordExtract method I get `nasa rocket hopkins`

Answer (score 1):

Your first list is `['nasa', 'rocket', 'hopkins']`. Your `KeyWordExtract` just takes a list and returns the concatenated strings separated by space.

To do what you want to do, replace

```
myString = " ".join(keyWord_List)
```

with

```
myString = ' '.join(''.join(keyWord_List))
```

The result is as follows:

```
>>> list = ['nasa', 'rocket', 'hopkins']
>>> ' '.join(''.join(list))
'n a s a r o c k e t h o p k i n s'
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same problem with the second bit of code

Comment: I'm trying to get it to be `'nasa rocket hopkins`

Comment: So the end result should be `nasa rocket hopkins`? Your function already returns that.

Comment: exactly but it doesn't when I automate the search

Comment: If you want, you can print out `search_terms` and see its value before calling the `send_keys` function. If the value is correct and you still get the same problem, look into the `send_keys` function and see how it handles the value it gets.